# Can I have notifications/alerts sent by IM to a Skype account from a headless machine?

Tags: command-line-interface, alerts, skype, headless

I want to make my network monitoring system send IM alerts, and the IM client of choice at my workplace is Skype.

Is there a command-line driven API, that doesn't require the GUI Skype client, so I can run it on the Linux machines that run my monitoring?

Alternatively, is there a Jabber-to-Skype gateway that would solve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to common wisdom, [including this SuperUser post](https://superuser.com/questions/28755/skype-messenger-for-linux-console), Skype has not been reverse engineered, and they do not offer a command-line only client.

There are a number of options for controlling a GUI client from the command line, including [Skype4py](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4536146/need-an-python-script-that-uses-skype4py-to-send-an-instant-message) and [skype-command-line (Java)](http://code.google.com/p/skype-command-line/).

Answer (score 1):

http://code.google.com/p/skype-command-line/

Comment: This calls the GUI Skype client, so doesn't fit the requirements.  Thanks for the suggestion though and welcome to ServerFault.

Comment: @crb: If your only objection to the GUI client is that it requires a GUI, run it on a headless X server such as `Xvfb` or `Xvnc`.

Comment: I object more to the fact I need to have Qt and X on a tiny machine, vs. an open protocol like Jabber where this would be trivial :)  I was under the impression that Skype had been reverse engineered, just a little.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am totally late, but there is a simple service to send server alerts to Skype and other IM platforms: https://ezalert.me

It also has an email gateway that can forward alert emails via IM.